# About the vtable symbol may be undefined because the class is missing its key function

Tags: android, c++, clang++

I want to debug android native source code, so I change clang optimization level `-Os` -> `-O0`
error:

> frameworks/native/services/surfaceflinger/DisplayHardware/HWComposer_hwc1.h:171:error: undefined reference to 'vtable for android::HWComposer::HWCLayerInterface'
>           prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/aarch64/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/aarch64-linux-android/bin/ld.gold: the vtable symbol may be undefined because the class is missing its key function (see go/missingkeymethod)
>           frameworks/native/services/surfaceflinger/DisplayHardware/HWComposer_hwc1.h:171: error: undefined reference to 'vtable for android::HWComposer::HWCLayerInterface'
>           prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/aarch64/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/aarch64-linux-android/bin/ld.gold: the vtable symbol may be undefined because the class is missing its key function (see go/missingkeymethod)
>           frameworks/native/services/surfaceflinger/DisplayHardware/HWComposer_hwc1.h:171: error: undefined reference to 'vtable for android::HWComposer::HWCLayerInterface'
>           prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/aarch64/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/aarch64-linux-android/bin/ld.gold: the vtable symbol may be undefined because the class is missing its key function (see go/missingkeymethod)
>           frameworks/native/services/surfaceflinger/DisplayHardware/HWComposer_hwc1.h:171: error: undefined reference to 'vtable for android::HWComposer::HWCLayerInterface'
>           prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/aarch64/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/aarch64-linux-android/bin/ld.gold: the vtable symbol may be undefined because the class is missing its key function (see go/missingkeymethod)
>           out/target/product/rk3399_box/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libsurfaceflinger_intermediates/DisplayHardware/HWComposer_hwc1.o:frameworks/native/services/surfaceflinger/DisplayHardware/HWComposer_hwc1.cpp:vtable for android::Iterable: error: undefined reference to 'android::HWComposer::HWCLayerInterface::setDataspace(android_dataspace)'
>           out/target/product/rk3399_box/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libsurfaceflinger_intermediates/DisplayHardware/HWComposer_hwc1.o:frameworks/native/services/surfaceflinger/DisplayHardware/HWComposer_hwc1.cpp:vtable for android::HWComposer::HWCLayer: error: undefined reference to 'android::HWComposer::HWCLayerInterface::setDataspace(android_dataspace)'
>           clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I don't want to modify the android source code, but I want to close optimization.

HWCLayerInterface:

```
    class HWCLayerInterface {
    protected:
        virtual ~HWCLayerInterface() { }
    public:
        virtual int32_t getCompositionType() const = 0;
        virtual uint32_t getHints() const = 0;
        virtual sp<Fence> getAndResetReleaseFence() = 0;
        virtual void setDefaultState() = 0;
        virtual void setSkip(bool skip) = 0;
        virtual void setIsCursorLayerHint(bool isCursor = true) = 0;
        virtual void setBlending(uint32_t blending) = 0;
        virtual void setTransform(uint32_t transform) = 0;
        virtual void setFrame(const Rect& frame) = 0;
        virtual void setCrop(const FloatRect& crop) = 0;
        virtual void setVisibleRegionScreen(const Region& reg) = 0;
        virtual void setSurfaceDamage(const Region& reg) = 0;
        virtual void setSidebandStream(const sp<NativeHandle>& stream) = 0;
        virtual void setBuffer(const sp<GraphicBuffer>& buffer) = 0;
        virtual void setAcquireFenceFd(int fenceFd) = 0;
        virtual void setPlaneAlpha(uint8_t alpha) = 0;
        virtual void onDisplayed() = 0;
        virtual void setDataspace(android_dataspace_t dataspace);
    };
```

HWCLayer:

```
    class HWCLayer : public HWCLayerInterface {
        friend class LayerListIterator;
        // select the layer at the given index
        virtual status_t setLayer(size_t index) = 0;
        virtual HWCLayer* dup() = 0;
        static HWCLayer* copy(HWCLayer *rhs) {
            return rhs ? rhs->dup() : NULL;
        }
    protected:
        virtual ~HWCLayer() { }
    };
```

Iterable:

```
    template<typename CONCRETE, typename HWCTYPE>
    class Iterable : public HWComposer::HWCLayer {
    protected:
        HWCTYPE* const mLayerList;
        HWCTYPE* mCurrentLayer;
        Iterable(HWCTYPE* layer) : mLayerList(layer), mCurrentLayer(layer),
                mIndex(0) { }
        inline HWCTYPE const * getLayer() const { return mCurrentLayer; }
        inline HWCTYPE* getLayer() { return mCurrentLayer; }
        virtual ~Iterable() { }
        size_t mIndex;
    private:
        // returns a copy of ourselves
        virtual HWComposer::HWCLayer* dup() {
            return new CONCRETE( static_cast<const CONCRETE&>(*this) );
        }
        virtual status_t setLayer(size_t index) {
            mIndex = index;
            mCurrentLayer = &mLayerList[index];
            return NO_ERROR;
        }
    };
```

HWCLayerVersion1:

```
    class HWCLayerVersion1 : public Iterable<HWCLayerVersion1, hwc_layer_1_t> {
        struct hwc_composer_device_1* mHwc;
    public:
    ......
        virtual void setDataspace(android_dataspace_t dataspace) {
            getLayer()->reserved[0] = dataspace & 0xFF;
            getLayer()->reserved[1] = (dataspace >> 8) & 0xFF;
            getLayer()->reserved[2] = (dataspace >> 16) & 0xFF;
            getLayer()->reserved[3] = (dataspace >> 24) & 0xFF;
        }
    }
```

When I change optimization level to `-O2` or :

```
class HWCLayerInterface {
    protected:
        virtual ~HWCLayerInterface() { }
    public:
        virtual int32_t getCompositionType() const = 0;
        virtual uint32_t getHints() const = 0;
        virtual sp<Fence> getAndResetReleaseFence() = 0;
        virtual void setDefaultState() = 0;
        virtual void setSkip(bool skip) = 0;
        virtual void setIsCursorLayerHint(bool isCursor = true) = 0;
        virtual void setBlending(uint32_t blending) = 0;
        virtual void setTransform(uint32_t transform) = 0;
        virtual void setFrame(const Rect& frame) = 0;
        virtual void setCrop(const FloatRect& crop) = 0;
        virtual void setVisibleRegionScreen(const Region& reg) = 0;
        virtual void setSurfaceDamage(const Region& reg) = 0;
        virtual void setSidebandStream(const sp<NativeHandle>& stream) = 0;
        virtual void setBuffer(const sp<GraphicBuffer>& buffer) = 0;
        virtual void setAcquireFenceFd(int fenceFd) = 0;
        virtual void setPlaneAlpha(uint8_t alpha) = 0;
        virtual void onDisplayed() = 0;
        //change to default implemented
        virtual void setDataspace(android_dataspace_t dataspace) = 0;
    };
```

This error does not exist.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

`= 0` does not mean default implemented, it means not implemented — you're reserving the ability to call `setDataspace` on pointers and references to a `HWCLayerInterface` but there is no implementation of `HWCLayerInterface::setDataspace`.

If you omit the `= 0` then you promise that there's an implementation of `HWCLayerInterface::setDataspace` somewhere, and the linker will expect it to exist. The error you get is the linker telling you that you promised it an implementation of that method but didn't provide one.

Optimisation level is irrelevant, the C++ code is incorrect if you declare a method but don't also define it.

So:

- if you want to define a virtual function that children **must** override, declare it as `= 0`;
- if you want to define a virtual function that children **may** override, but want the function to do nothing if not overridden, declare it as empty — e.g. `virtual void setDataspace(android_dataspace_t dataspace) {}`.

For good maintenance, you should mark anything you override as `override`. The compiler will then check that you really have overridden something. That'll protect you against both hard-to-spot typos and changes in the parent class that you fail to track, either of which can make your attempted override into just some freestanding function. Also look into `final` and when it's appropriate to apply to a class and/or an overridden function.